# Python SimpleHTTPServer Access from Outside Network

Tags: python-2.7, simplehttpserver

I've tried searching online for this -- is it somehow possible to open up the localhosted server python's SimpleHTTPServer creates to computers outside of my network?

Comment: Forward the localhosts ip adress on the router

Comment: Thanks for your help, EL3PANTEN -- could you explain a bit what you mean here? When I enter my IP address into the browser from another computer off my network, it goes nowhere

Comment: If you are on your local network, You usually enter 192.168.1.1 To get into the router settings. User: admin, passwd: admin.. In advanced settings you forward the local ip of your server. For example 192.168.1.100 or whatever your local server machine is. Ususally you can see it in the settings, wich ip adresses are connected.

Comment: Also you shall know that you cannot connect to your external ip while on local network. You must use proxy server to test it.. hidemyass.com for example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run python SimpleHTTPServer on localhost only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only)