# 0.0.0.0:8000 working in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to use SimpleHTTPServer to debug some ReactJS code, and when I use Firefox, I can see the page fine, but when I browse using Chrome:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

It execute a Google search for that and doesn't actually go to the address.

Any ideas of what is going on here?  How can I force Chrome to go to that address instead of doing a search?

Comment: Use a real IP address. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: @Quentin, but that's the default IP served up by SimpleHTTPServer, not to mention the fact that Firefox renders it fine.  Is there no way to view this in Chrome?

Comment: It's not the IP, it just means it is listening on all the network interfaces, so you can use any IP the box has.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin looks like FF and Chrome interpret 0.0.0.0 differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the server running on your PC? You should try http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP

EDIT: I found also this answer: [Is it possible to run python SimpleHTTPServer on localhost only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only)

Comment: Localhost worked fine, I guess FireFox assumes localhost and renders fine, and Chrome defaults to a web search, it's interesting - thanks!