# Simple python webserver blocked on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, webserver, windows-10

I'm running a simple python webserver exactly as [per this page](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/create-simple-rest-web-service-with-python.php) except on Windows 10. The localhost seems to be blocked when I start the service. I authorised the python.exe and pycharm applications when the Windows firewall asked me. `web.application` creates a server on http://0.0.0.0:8080. Is there some added security in Win 10 that I have to remove to make this work?

Comment: You can try to specify a local ip address, other than 0.0.0.0. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only

Answer (score 1):

Based on Pedro's comment, it worked after restricting localhost to 127.0.0.1 done by adding the IP address as the first script parameter. i.e. `.\webservice.py 127.0.0.1`