# Python 3 and http.server usage

Tags: python, http

I was wondering if I have index.html and in windows CMD run `python -m http.server 80` while in the directory with index.html will it start a server on my IP(given I have port 80 open) and then people can just connect to my IP and see what is in index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

1. your router is portforwarded for TCP 80
2. the server is listening on 0.0.0.0
3. No firewalls are in the way

Then it will be publically accessible. To make it only available on local host you should host on 127.0.0.1

```
httpd = ServerClass(("127.0.0.1", 80), HandlerClass)
```

Edit: the other answer posted this good link, didn't see until after posting: [Is it possible to run python SimpleHTTPServer on localhost only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only)

Comment: So then it returning `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 80 ...` is not an error?

Comment: No, 0.0.0.0 means "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine".

Comment: 127.0.01 is the loop back address. See here for more info: http://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

Comment: You can use this website to check if your site is accessible: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com
Paste your public IP in there, found by google "what is my ip"

Comment: Thanks, looks like ill be calling my ISP to see if they are blocking portforwarding

Comment: please note that you can't access your own computer by its public IP from within your own network (due to NAT punchthrough, I believe, not sure)

Answer (score 0):

People should be able to connect to your public IP without problem. It would be a little more complex if you want to give access only from localhost:

[Is it possible to run python SimpleHTTPServer on localhost only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only)